# Do these sets equal each other?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Find the set  $$ \cap_{k=5}^\infty  [\cup_{n=3}^k X_n]$$
Where  $$X_n=\{ n+1, n+2, \cdots, 2n \} $$

I think this set is equal to {4,5,6,7,8,9,10}

Is this correct?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add that X(index n) = {n+1,n+2,...2n} for n in the positive naturals.

Comment: It would help tremendously if you take the time to correctly type all parts of the problem so that people don't have to click on an image to read a single line.  [Read how to use MathJax here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  Also, this does not have to do with the concept of multi-sets and so that tag is irrelevant.

Comment: As for your question, yes, it is correct.  An easy way to recognize this is that $[\bigcup_{n=3}^a X_n] \subseteq [\bigcup_{n=3}^b X_n]$ whenever $5\leq a\leq b$, implying that the sets over which you are intersecting are "*nested*" which implies that the intersection results in just the smallest of the nested sets.  In general, if $A_1\subseteq A_2\subseteq A_3\subseteq\dots$ then $\bigcap_{i=1}^N A_i = A_1$

Answer (score 0):

Because the intersected sets are increasing, you only need to evalute the union for k=5, thus you're correct.